# Java Generics - Using the generic type parameter of the enclosing class in a method parameter

Tags: java, generics

I've a simple generic class follows which accepts a generic type parameter, which is the same as the one declared as a type parameter of the class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public abstract class SimpleClass<T extends AnnotatedElement>
{

   public void operate()
   {
      Method m = null;
      this.doSomething(m); // Error : SimpleClass.java:[34,10] doSomething(T) in SimpleClass<T> cannot be applied to (java.lang.reflect.Method)
   }
   protected abstract void doSomething(T annotatedElement);
}
```

This code fails to compile at the following line:

```
this.doSomething(m);
```

with this error:

```
Error : SimpleClass.java:[34,10] doSomething(T) in SimpleClass<T> cannot be applied to (java.lang.reflect.Method)
```

Am I missing something here? The type parameter T is marked as T extends AnnotatedElement. As such, I would expect the call to doSomething with a java.lang.reflect.Method argument to compile successfully.

Comment: First thoughts: `Method` isn't a subclass of `AnnotatedElement`, but rather a class that implements it.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: That is irrelevant here.

Comment: @JeremyHeller: I realized that after reading the Java spec, but SO was screwing up and wouldn't let me delete that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method implements AnnotatedElement, but that doesn't require that T is a method. What if the class is declared as `SimpleClass<Constructor>`? That satisfies `<T extends AnnotatedElement>`, but doesn't support conversion from `Method`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. But to take it a bit further, if I change my class and method definition to:
`public abstract class SimpleClass<T extends AnnotatedElement>
{

   public void operate()
   {
      Method m = null;
      this.doSomething(m); // Compiles now!
   }
   protected abstract <U extends AnnotatedElement> void doSomething(U annotatedElement);
}`

it starts compiling fine!

Comment: @Java User: That is because you are defining a method-level generic, which doesn't depend on the generic defined on the class.

Comment: Sorry about that formatting, I'm having a hard time getting it to show up correctly

Comment: and @Jeremy, thanks for explaining it. I now understand what's going on. Also, I guess I need to do some reading around generics to really wrap my head around it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Java: Yes, it compiles, but within that method, you now have two generic types: T and U, which both implement AnnotatedElement, but may or may not be related.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know that T is a `Method`. It could just as well be e.g. a `Package`, and then your operate() wouldn't make sense, trying to pass a `Method` to something expecting `Package`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `T` doesn't matter here. All you know is that the type is `AnnotatedElement`.

The following change would make it compile:

```
 protected abstract void doSomething(AnnotatedElement annotatedElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic method is not implemented correctly. Change your generic method to

```
protected abstract<T extends AnnotatedElement> void doSomething(T annotatedElement);
```

Above statement creates correct generic method. This will remove compilation error.